# Which of the following options is best suited for the given statement?

Tags: comprehension, exam-questions

The English exam question is which option would best suit as a conclusion for the statement?

> The Pacific yew is an evergreen tree that grows in the Pacific Northwest. The Pacific yew has a fleshy, poisonous fruit. Recently, taxol, a substance found in the bark of the Pacific yew, was discovered to be a promising new anticancer drug.

- A.   Taxol is poisonous when taken by healthy people.
- B.   Taxol has cured people from various diseases.
- C.   People should not eat the fruit of the Pacific yew.
- D.   The Pacific yew was considered worthless until taxol was discovered.

I would say it would be D. The Pacific yew was considered worthless until taxol was discovered. My reasoning behind that would be that the fruit was considered worthless until the anti cancer drug was discoverd. A and B do not follow. C does follow but I think C would have been best suited had the information "The Pacific yew was considered worthless until taxol was discovered." not been provided.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about logical conclusions, not features of the English language.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I thought this site was for people trying to learn English? This is a standard type of question that turns up in thousands of official EFL tests (e.g. IELTS, FCE etc etc). If we can't help learners with this type of question then let's close down the site. Now!

Comment: Hi Kaustabha! Welcome to ELL :) Is this question from an IELTS test? Where did you find the question?

Comment: @Araucaria: I can certainly see how the exam question *could* challenge someone's ability to read English. But I don't see that *this question* is about any of the aspects of that exam question that have to do with English. (It's obviously in no way "proofreading", however. That's absurd.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Well the OP has given us the exam question. They have given us their own thinking about the answer. Their question seems to be the exam question itself, no? (Btw, in my comment above I had misread your comment further above. Have edited it!) In other words which option is correct and why ...

Comment: @Araucaria This was a question in an exam in India, not from IELTS

Comment: @KaustabhaRay What's the name of the exam?

Comment: @Araucaria It was in the Aptitude portion of the Scientist Entrance Examination for for Computer Scientists at National Institute of Electronics and Information Technology

Comment: @KaustabhaRay Ah, in that case, this may not be the best site for your question ... I'm not sure. Let's see what happens.

Comment: I, too, think it's not a question about the language per se but about reading comprehension and logic. The Wicked Witch of the West makes a delicious Pacific yew and red herring pie.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Why do you think it's D? I think it's C.

Comment: It's C for me too. That, or we should not visit the Pacific Northwest, which has a high cancer rate because of all of the taxol in the aquafer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how one defines "conclusion." If it means what is the "best" thing to take away (*ie* conclude) from the statement, then yes C is the best; here the conclusion is not part of the text. And D's statement that the tree was considered worthless is unsubstantiated.

However, and here is how the exam question could have been eminently concerned with learning English, because *writing* is one of the four basic skills... *If* this question were asking  the student to identify which of four sentences serves as the best conclusion (meaning *concluding sentence*) to the given statement (text), then, were this  the case,  the learner would have  to evaluate many things about the statement, including its style, purpose,  intended audience, etc.  This all has to do with *language learning*. The thinking process would be as follows:

This text gives us a kind of history of this tree. A concluding sentence will use the same style. D continues the history of the tree, giving us a new bit of information (it was considered worthless until...) and connecting that back with the most important fact that the text mentions (taxol was discovered). This is a successful conclusion, even if "Pacific (Yew)" is somewhat repetitious. Sentence C does not fit in with the style (description) or purpose (give a history) of the text. It grossly inserts a personal prescription/directive to people, including the reader. It is out of place. It is not even close to being a good concluding sentence *for this text  as a text*.

However, since this is not the purpose of the test  and this is not what is meant by *conclusion*, I am much harder pressed to see what the question has to do with learning English.

Comment: Conclusion in the question is closer to No. 1 definition of [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conclusion):  a reasoned judgment: **inference**. People could have cut it and used it as firewood. There is nothing that indicates it was worthless which makes D invalid. The only answer that we can infer from the quote is "we should not eat the fruit as it is poisonous". As Araucaria mentioned in the comment, it is a typical question in English tests.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks which of four options *"would best suit as a conclusion for the statement"* made of three sentences. Hence options A, B, C and D are not additional facts, but are statements that may be derived from the three sentences.

As a question on comprehension is it clever. It carefully mixes two sets of facts about the tree. One set concerns the poisonous fruit. The other concerns taxol which is extracted from the bark and is a promising new anticancer drug.

As a piece of English text it is poor because it leaves the reader confused about the two sets of facts.

Looking at the four possible conclusions in turn:

**A**: Is there something about being unhealthy that would make Taxol more or less poisonous to them as compared to healthy people? I think not. Taxol is almost certainly equally poisonous (or not poisonous) to both healthy and unhealthy people.

**B**: The text says Taxol is promising as a drug, not that it has cured anyone.

**C**: The fruit is poisonous. Eating poisons is, generally, a bad thing to do. So not eating that fruit is good advice.

**D**: The text says nothing about other uses of the tree. It just says the fruit is poisonous and the bark contains Taxol. The wood from many types of tree has been used for making things. Eg furniture; longbows from English Yew; bows and canoe paddles from Pacific Yew.

My analysis would suggest **C** is the best conclusion.

Comment: Did you miss that part about the anticancer drug?

Comment: There is nothing in the those three original sentences that describes **taxol** as toxic.  I agree that we are told the fruit is poisonous.

Comment: @J.R. Please explain further. I thought I had covered that point with *"B: The text says Taxol is promising as a drug, not that it has cured anyone"*.

Comment: @TRomano Thank you. Yes, I will modify that part of my answer.

Comment: It "just says" the tree has a recently-discovered substance that might cure cancer. You think that eliminates D?

Comment: @J.R. The tree may be valuable for many other reasons, I named some. Suggestion D says it *"was considered worthless until taxol was discovered"*. The opening text makes no comment on other use of the tree.

Comment: I'll say it more plainly: I think "D" does a much better job of capturing the overall thrust of the paragraph than "C" does. "C" is true, but it explains why the tree was considered worthless until taxol was discovered. Now, the test writers would mark [your answer right and my answer wrong](http://www.indiabix.com/logical-reasoning/verbal-reasoning/discussion-349), but I think that speaks to the unfortunate fact that exam writers often write [bad test questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=bad+english+test+questions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) – and this is one of them.

Comment: Given the wording of the question in the link @J.R. posted, I actually agree with C as the answer. It's still not a great question, but C is the only answer with enough support in the text provided to be considered "true".  If the goal was the write the next sentence of the paragraph, D would probably be better, though it relies on the writer knowing more about the tree than is presented in the text, specifically, that it was considered worthless.

Comment: +1 to your comment @Tofystedeth Although  the writer can be considered as the one supplying the  information about the tree and thus the bit about its having been considered worthless is something new he tells us.

Comment: @Tofystedeth - You nailed it. The question in the link asks: _Find the statement that **must be true** according to the given information._ That would be "C". However, the O.P. wrote: _Which option would best suit as a **conclusion**_. While "C" must be true, but it doesn't seem like much of a conclusion, particularly for the paragraph as a whole. I assumed the test makers were wanting the student to conclude information from all three statements.

Comment: @J.R. I don't understand where you get the idea that the tree was considered worthless. There's nothing about the value of the tree in the statement, which is why I would rule D. It may or may not have been considered worthless, but there's nothing in the text that supports that conclusion. There are plenty of plants (and creatures!) with poisonous parts that are very valuable, so I don't think it's correct to assume poisonous fruit means worthless.

Comment: @Colleen - True. I will say this, though: If I were the author, and I knew the trees had been valued before the taxol discovery, I probably wouldn't have written the paragraph the way it is written. Though prior "worthlessness" is not explicitly stated, the 3-sentence paragraph is written in a way that might easily (and perhaps deliberately, in this case) lead a reader to assume that the trees have a lot more value now than they did before. In that regard, it's a bit of a "trap question" – it seems to test more about attention to detail and assumptions than a grasp on the English language.

Comment: @J.R. Your comment that *"I probably wouldn't have written the paragraph the way it is written"* is, I believe, very pertinent. As a piece of English text the sentences to be examined are poor and confusing. As part of a question on comprehension they are quite clever. The question is from an examination for the *"Scientist Entrance Examination for for[sic] Computer Scientists"* and in that context I would expect the question to be more about understanding the facts etc than about being well written prose.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - Fair enough, but when I made my initial comment, the O.P. only revealed that it was an "English exam question" asking for the "best suited conclusion for the statement" – not a Science Entrance Exam question asking which of the options must be true based on the preceding text. Had that been made more clear, I would have analyzed the question differently. I also think your latest revision explains the situation quite well.